# dependencies of a haskell project

Tags: haskell, version, cabal, haskell-stack

If I `stack unpack hakyll-4.9.2.0` I see in the cabal file

```
Build-Depends:
    base                 >= 4.8    && < 5,
    ...
  If flag(checkExternal)
    Build-depends:
      http-conduit >= 2.2    && < 2.3,
```

After doing `stack init` the resolver selected is `lts-7.14` which only contains `http-conduit` version `2.1.11` (cf https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.14/package/http-conduit-2.1.11)

However it does compile, and doing `stack  list-dependencies --flag hakyll:checkExternal | grep -i http` yields

```
...
http-conduit 2.1.11
```

which is surprising.

When I change the resolver to `nightly-2016-12-28`in stack.yaml, it shows a dependency on

```
$ stack  list-dependencies --flag hakyll:checkExternal | grep -i http
http-conduit 2.2.3
```

Is there an explanation of whats could go on here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Stack, the resolver value fully specifies which packages are available. Changing flags does not in any way affect which package versions can be used.